# How to make CAKeyframeAnimation interact by user during the period of the animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

`CAKeyframeAnimation` doesn't like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
    ..
} completion:nil];
```

We can't set up `options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction`. Does anyone have a good idea to make it interact by user during the period of the animation?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue setting a Timer to update the frame during the animation.

```
//Timer: To update the UI frame
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.15, target: self, selector: #selector(updateFrame), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

//Timer Selector
@objc func updateFrame(){
    //getting the layer presentation bounds
    let layer = "button, label...".layer.presentation()!

    let point = CGPoint(x: layer.frame.origin.x, y: layer.frame.origin.y)
    let size = CGSize(width: layer.frame.width, height: layer.frame.height)
    // Update the UI element frame location
    "ui element".frame = CGRect(origin: point, size: size)
}
```